# How do I hide a report path from a breadcrumb in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services

I have created a report with 3 parameters and uploaded it in Report manager in SSRS. I have a asp.net web page where I have a hyperlink that has the URL to open the report in the report server. Now when the report opens user can see the report path on the breadcrumb. My question is how to hide that?
My hyperlink is

```
<asp:HyperLink ID = "hlIntCharge" runat="server" Text="Interest Charges Report" CssClass="buttonClass" Width="165px" 
NavigateUrl="javascript:GoTo('https://<Servername>/ReportsDev/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fCFM%2fCurrentGeneralLedger%2fInterestCharges')"></asp:HyperLink>
```

I have tried `&rv:Toolbar=false` after the link but didn't work.

I cannot change style as suggested in a link by going

> :\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting
>   Services\ ReportManager

as I don't have permission.

Answer (score 0):

Use the URL from the report server not the one from the reports manager.

Try accessing it by typing the domain name/ReportServer. See sameple below.

```
http://server-name.com/ReportServer
```

Comment: I am sorry, for some reason my url didn't show the whole thing. This is what I have:   https://sERVERNAME/ReportsDev/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fCFM%2fCurrentGeneralLedger%2fInterestCharges. I just changed the real server name with the word SERVERNAME.

Comment: I don't know why it is deleting the https:// at the front and the rest of the link after the Pages/

Comment: This is not the right heading for this question. I will add this with right question heading.